# Objective-C - Avoid compile error?

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

Is there a way to suppress a compile error?
I cannot use protocols in this case because the class I am trying to use is in an external library. I have no control over the code

```
if (myClass && [[myClass class] respondsToSelector:@selector(getSomething)])
{
   // Compile error on the line below
   MyResult *result = [myClass getSomething];

   // Also tried
   MyResult *result = [(id)myClass getSomething];

}
```

**EDIT:**
Error: No known class method for selector

Comment: GDB and LLDB are debuggers, not compilers. The compilers Apple supports are GCC and Clang.

Comment: What do lldb & gdb have to do with compiling? Besides that, what's the error?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The compilers don't know about the class method you're trying to use. Did you `#import` the right file?

Comment: @zneak But this class can be anything, I want to call that method on any class that responds to it

Comment: Is it an error or just a warning?  (And you can always create a dummy class or protocol that defines the methods you want to call, then cast to that class/protocol.)

Comment: @aryaxt, when you use a method on an untyped Objective-C object, the compiler tries to guess which method you're trying to call based on its selector, because it needs to generate different code depending on the return value. Without ARC, the compiler will assume the return type is `id` for any selector it doesn't know and generate a warning. With ARC, it becomes a hard error because the compiler doesn't want to take a chance at memory management. That's why you at least need to tell the compiler about one existing declaration of the method.

Comment: Error, I have it setup in the build setting to treat warnings as error. So I need to get rid of that warning

Comment: Importing the abstract class that the rest of them inherit from changed the error to a warning. Now I need to get rid of the warning

Comment: Casting to id got rid of the warning. zneak why don't you put your tips as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @aryaxt are you trying to use a non-public method on the class?

Comment: @CarlVeazey No and the problem is resolved already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a method on an untyped Objective-C object, the compiler tries to guess which method you're trying to call based on its selector, because it needs to generate different code depending on the return value. The way code is generated is also different depending on if you use ARC or not, and the compiler needs change accordingly.

Without ARC, the compiler will assume the return type is `id`  for any selector it doesn't know of, and will generate a warning. With ARC, it becomes a hard error because the compiler doesn't want to take a chance at memory management.

That's why you at least need to tell the compiler about one existing declaration of the method.

Comment: An alternative solution is to declare a category with the method;  `@interface SomeClass (MethodsThatExistThatAreNotDeclaredThisIsBadCodeAndIFeelBad) decl @end` at the top of the `.m` file that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

This article describes how to use a #pragma declaration to avoid compiler warnings for cases where you are certain the warning is a false positive (or one that you believe is safe to ignore): [NSHipster - #pragma](http://nshipster.com/pragma/)

Comment: Which it is not a false positive in this case.

Comment: True. I added a parenthetical to clarify my intention.